# Revolution/rxMerge and duplication of rows

Tags: r, revolution-r

I am trying to merge two xdf files after subsetting a long table that has duplicate ids based on a variable.

Assume I have two columns: id and type

I subset the original xdf table based on say `type = 'type1'`, and get first xdf file
I subset the original xdf table based on say `type = 'type2'`, and get second xdf file

The first xdf file looks like 
(There are quite a few number of distinct IDs, but I show one ID in the example below)

```
id type1
__ ____
1    5
```

The second xdf file looks like
(There are quite a few number of distinct IDs, but I show one ID in the example below)

```
id type2
__ ____
1    3
```

Then, I merge the two xdf files into another xdf file

```
rxMerge(file1, file2, outFile = final, autoSort = FALSE, matchVars = 'id', type = 'full', overwrite = TRUE)
```

I get two records for id = 1 as in

```
id type1 type2
__ ____ ______
1    5    NA

1    NA    3
```

I was expecting

```
id type1 type2
__ ____ ______
1    5    3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... your example as given works for me, in RRE 7.4.1:

```
# Example data
x <- data.frame(id = 1, type1 = 5)
y <- data.frame(id = 1, type2 = 3)

# Creating XDFs for the example data
file1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".xdf")
rxImport(inData = x, outFile = file1)

file2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".xdf")
rxImport(inData = y, outFile = file2)

# Merging into a third XDF
final <- tempfile(fileext = ".xdf")

rxMerge(inData1 = file1, 
        inData2 = file2, 
        outFile = final, 
        autoSort = FALSE, 
        matchVars = 'id',
        type = 'full',
        overwrite = TRUE)

# Check the output
rxDataStep(final)
```

So it's hard to know what might be going on. What happens when you set `autoSort = TRUE`? What version of RRE are you running? (You can get version numbers by loading RevoScaleR and running `sessionInfo()`)